# Arranging elements horizontally in ArcGIS tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, geoprocessing

Is it possible to arrange multiple check boxes horizontally in a tool and changing the parameters dynamically (adding/removing) based on user selection of check boxes?

Answer (score 2):

Nope. Regarding organizing the parameters, the closest you could come in doing this is to organize your parameters into categories.

See the ArcGIS Help Documentation for [defining parameters in a Python Toolbox](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Defining_parameters_in_a_Python_toolbox/001500000028000000/) for more information (Parameter categories are at the very bottom of the page).

In terms of updating your parameters, you can't make them appear/disappear. But you can use the updateParameters method to enable or disable them based on user input, as well as dynamically populate the default value of a given parameter based on the user input to another parameter.

Comment: It's theoretically possible with a custom stylesheet but it's such a ridiculous hassle it might as well be impossible

Comment: How would one apply a style sheet to a script tool or pyt?

Comment: [Here is some old (but still valid) documentation](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Changing_tool_dialog_appearance). It works on script tools, it's not exposed on Python Toolboxes. There's a lot of HTML and XSLT trickery involved.